# WMS request fails

Tags: wms, mapserver

I am trying to set up a WMS server using MapServer. As per the documentation http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html, I have added the metadata required for WMS and trying to hit the following URL:

http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=mywms.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&

But eventually what I get is just the `mapserv.exe` which gets downloaded every time. Could someone tell me where I could be wrong.

Below is the metadata for WMS:

```
"wms_title" "WMS Demo Server"
"wms_onlineresource" "http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/.../.../xyz.map"
"wms_srs" "EPSG:4269 EPSG:4326"
"wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
"wms_enable_request" "*"
```

And below is the request:

http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=C:/ms4w/Apache/htdocs/.../.../xyz.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&

Comment: Try a WMS 1.3.0 request, it has a different mime type and it will show in your browser.  For a default configuration you can't change the format of the GetCapabilities response.  The parameter you have set is for the response of a GetFeatureInfo request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [MapServer FAQ](http://www.mapserver.org/faq.html#when-i-do-a-getcapabilities-why-does-my-browser-want-to-download-mapserv-exe-mapserv) but this isn't actually the executable but the capabilities document and your browser doesn't recognize the mime type of application/vnd.ogc.xml

Comment: I have defined the mime type under the metadata as following :
"wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"

Comment: but capabilities documents have a mime type of application/vnd.ogc.xml

Comment: please have a look at the question where I have pasted the metadata and the request URL.

Comment: please read the FAQ I linked to which answers this question. If you open up the file returned it is in fact xml inside.